# IBM Worklight - difference between Rational Test Workbench and Mobile Test Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww, rational-test-workbench

I know that the Rational Test Workbench Eclipse client can test non-Worklight applications and the other components of RTW are for web testing; I am focused more on mobile testing.

I want to know the differences between RTW and Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight (MTWW), if there is any other, or are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rational Test Workbench is not dependent on Worklight.  There are 2 RTW Mobile test options -
1) Rational Test Workbench Mobile Test Edition, and
2) Rational Test Workbench Eclipse Client
Either of which can test worklight applications.  The difference is related not to Worklight, but to how the tool will be used in a scaled environment.

There is a version of RTW Mobile Test Edition that is included with and can be installed with Worklight called **IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight** that can only be used to test Worklight apps. (See the subheading "Testing with IBM Worklight in the Worklight online documentation.)

**RTW Mobile Test Edition** is a stand-alone mobile testing tool that can test mobile applications using either a simulated mobile device or a real mobile device.  (See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.rtwm.reldoc.doc/topics/rtwm_readme.html)

**RTW Eclipse Client** is a component of the Rational Test Workbench, and is the same thing as the RTW Mobile Test Edition, however, it can also be integrated with the features of other Rational Testing tools including Rational Integration Tester and Rational Quality Manager. (See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.rtw.reldoc.doc/topics/rtw_readme.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly the right forum for this type of a question (this is a programming oriented Q&A website), so may I suggest to read about:

- [Rational Test Workbench](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/rtw)
- [Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.mobtest.doc/topics/c_wl_mobile_test_ovw.html)

Each will list what each product does.

---

That said, if you're developing a Worklight app, use MTWW.
Only With MTWW can you test Worklight-based apps, be it Hybrid or Native.

> IBM Worklight includes IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight for
>   testing mobile applications. You can only test IBM Worklight
>   applications. To test mobile applications that are not developed with
>   IBM Worklight, consider purchasing IBM Rational® Test Workbench.